# Using CountIf function in VBA to count number of entries with a specific Month and Year (ignoring Day)

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I'm fairly new at VBA. Using Excel 2007 VBA, I'm trying to count the number of entries in the "H" column of the "WOMade" worksheet that have a date in a specific month and year (ignoring the day), but all the methods I've tried aren't working.

Among other ideas, I've tried:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("WOMade").Columns("H:H"), "June-15")
```

And

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Format(Sheets("WOMade").Columns("H:H"), "mmyyyy"), "062015")
```

And

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("WOMade").Columns("H:H"), "June/" & "/2015)
```

And

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("WOMade").Columns("H:H"), ">=" 6/1/2015, Sheets("WOMade").Columns("H:H"), < 7/1/2015)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the last example was the closest.

```
dim i as long
with Sheets("WOMade")
    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns("H:H"), ">="  & dateserial(2015, 6, 1), .Columns("H:H"), "<" & dateserial(2015, 7, 1))
    'or,
    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns("H:H"), ">="  & datevalue("6/1/2015"), .Columns("H:H"), "<" & datevalue("7/1/2015"))
    'or,
    i = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns("H:H"), ">=6/1/2015", .Columns("H:H"), "<7/1/2015")
end with
```

Comment: Looks like that's working! Thanks for the swift, effective response. Out of curiosity, is there any particular advantage to using With/End With instead of just putting Sheets("WOMade") right before .Columns?

Comment: Using a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) reduces the code. Your formula would have had to use `Sheets("WOMade")` at least twice in a single formula and possibly other times for commands that involved working with the value returned by the worksheet function. It also makes it harder to forget to explicitly define parentage.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Test()
        Sheets("WOMade").Select

```
    SetYear = 2015
    SetMonth = 1
    Count = 0

    i = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 8) <> ""
        ' Subtract for TRUE as it is stored as -1
        Count = Count - (Year(Cells(i, 8)) = SetYear And Month(Cells(i, 8)) = SetMonth)

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox Count
```

End Sub

Comment: Wouldn't that count all of the dates in Jul-2015 as well as the dates in Jun-2015? The OP stated he wanted to return a count *'that have a date in a specific month and year'*.

Comment: Simply remove the ">=" and replace with "="

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function CountOfYearMonth(r As Range, y As Integer, m As Integer) As Long

    Set r = Intersect(r, r.Parent.UsedRange) 'Don't iterate over more than you have to

    'Technically n is not necessary, you can just use CountOfYearMonth
    Dim n As Long, _
        c As Range, _
        d As Date

    For Each c In r.Cells        
        If IsDate(c.Value) Then 'Does the cell contain a date?
            d = CDate(c.Value) 'Convert, if so
            If month(d) = m And year(d) = y Then 'Check year and month
                n = n + 1 'If match, increment total
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    CountOfYearMonth = n 'Assign return value
End Function
```